# Angular 4 Swiper integration (js initialization)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, swiper.js

I'am learning angular 4 and stuck with 3rd party module integration into my angular project.

[Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/)

So, I've installed Swiper by this command `npm install swiper --save`, then I added paths for this module in `.angular-cli.json` file

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css",
  "../node_modules/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js",
  "../node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"
],
```

I've also added html like in example

```
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

But what is the best way to initialize js part of this module and where?

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
  var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true,

    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    }

    // And if we need scrollbar
    scrollbar{
      el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    },
  })
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't be adding Swiper's paths to `.angular-cli.json`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a better solution is to use the ngx-swiper-wrapper. It's specially developed for the integration of swiper in an angular project:

[github: ngx-swiper-wrapper](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper/tree/master)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok, I got it! ;)